# Does Issei Hyodo still have the Divider power after season 2?

Tags: high-school-dxd

In the last part of the second season of *Highschool DxD*, there is a fight between Issei Hyodo and the White Dragon's host who was using a special skill called Divider that divides his enemies powers to half every time he uses.

Issei managed to get rid of it from the White Dragon as it was a Fragment of Magical Device attached to the White Dragon guy's accessories. Then, after Issei defeats that guy, he gets the Divider Fragment and fuses it with his Dragon Booster on his right arm.

I hoped he would use that dividing power later in the next season, but what happened to it? Where did that power go?

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. I tried to clarify the title based on my understanding of the question body as best as I can, but if it's incorrect, feel free to [edit] and clarify/improve it more. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, He still has the divine divider power. Issei took a jewel from vali's sacred gear and therefore he was able to contact with predecessor hosts of white vanishing dragon which lets him to use divine dividing.

Comment: Edit: Issei took a jewel from vali's sacred gear and therefore he was able to contact with predecessor hosts of white vanishing dragon which lets him to use divine dividing. I cant remember if he uses it again since i completed this series 2 months ago.

Comment: Please include relevant sources and never put the explanation to your answer in a comment. You can always edit your post.